# How to Export the Data/ Table containing more than 100k records From an Access Database to an Excel format

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, export-to-excel, accessdatasource

How to Export the Data/ Table containing more than 100k records) From an Access Database to an Excel format. I tried by unchecking export data with formatting and layout option in .xlsx file format. But i can see that some data is missing in some records in the excel file.

Is there any other way to export the entire 100k records to excel without missing any data.?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Open the Access data table hit `CTRL-C` open Excel and hit `CTRL-V`. Your computer may be 'not responding' for a few minutes but worth a shot

**Option 2:** Open Excel > Data > (import)From Access (top left of window).  Navigate to your database/table/access file and follow the prompts.  Unfortunately i cant help you beyond this as I don't know your file structure

**Option 3** Export from Access into Excel. [I found this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-data-to-excel-64e974e6-ae43-4301-a53e-20463655b1a9) particularly useful, especially the part highlighting 'troubleshooting missing or incorrect values'